# With SAS and PROC TABULATE, how can I display a percentage for one subset of values and not ALL subsets?

Tags: sas

If I have, say, grades (A,B,C,D,E,F), and want to display the percentage and N of kids who got an A or B out of all kids, and ONLY that info, is it possible with PROC TABULATE?

I tried using multi-label formats, but with those I have to include all the other values in the format or they just show up in the PROC TABULATE results.  I'm looking for something like:

```
Kid Group----------Total N----------A or B N----------A or B %  
Group 1            100              25                25%
Group 2            100              10                10%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of any way to do it with tabulate right off hand.  It might be easiest to jut do it manually.

```
data grades;
input name $ 1-15  gender $ 16-16 grade 19-20;
datalines;
Anderson       M  75
Aziz           F  67
Bayer          M  77
Burke          F  63
Chung          M  85
Cohen          F  89
Drew           F  49
Dubos          M  41
Elliott        F  85
Hazelton       M  55
Hinton         M  85
Hung           F  98
Jacob          F  64
Janeway        F  51
Judson         F  89
Litowski       M  85
Malloy         M  79
Meyer          F  85
Nichols        M  58
Oliver         F  41
Park           F  77
Patel          M  73
Randleman      F  46
Robinson       M  64
Shien          M  55
Simonson       M  62
Smith N        M  71
Smith R        M  79
Sullivan       M  77
Swift          M  63
Wolfson        F  79
Wong           F  89
Zabriski       M  89
;
run;
proc sort data=grades;by gender;run;
data _null_;
    set grades end=last;
    by gender;
    if _n_=1 then do;
       put @1 "gender" @8 "total" @16 "A_or_B" @27 "pct";
    end;
    if first.gender then do;
         A_or_B=0;
         total=0;
    end;
    total+1;
    if grade ge 80 and grade le 100 then A_or_B+1;
    if last.gender then do;
         pct=A_or_B/total;
         put @1 gender @8 total @16 A_or_B @24 pct nlpct.;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response cmjohns.  I think I'm going to end up doing it manually via some data manipulation in a true data step instead of _NULL_ reporting as you demonstrated.  I'm marking this as the accepted answer for...you know...the manual approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Subset the raw dataset in PROC tabulate with where statement.
e.g. where grade in ('A', 'B')

Comment: I think if I do that, I'm eliminating all people with grades other than A and B, which means my total N will be off.